# UserWarning: Calling close() on already closed file. warn("Calling close() on already closed file.")

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, xlsxwriter, user-warning

This error is apparently stemming from xlsxwriter. I'm not sure on what line of my code it's coming from because my editor Visual Studio 2019 crashes every time I try to debug. But, I get this error on a laptop while on a VPN and remote desktop connection. If I run the same code from my remote machine I don't get the error. The error doesn't seem to affect the output, though, because the script finishes and saves successfully. But, how do I get rid of this error?

My Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from datetime import datetime
import os

#set the headers as a browser
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
#set up file name
file_path = r"C:\Users\jpilbeam"
excel_file = 'bargetraffic' + str(datetime.now().strftime('_%m_%d_%Y')) + '.xlsx'
excel_file_full = os.path.join(file_path, excel_file)

lockName = ['Dresden Island Lock', 'Brandon Rd Lock', 'Lockport Lock']
lockNo = ['02', '03', '04']

results = []
for lock in lockNo: 
    url = 'https://corpslocks.usace.army.mil/lpwb/xml.lockqueue?in_river=IL&in_lock=' + lock
    #print (url)
    link = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')
    
    #get elements of row tags
    rows = soup.find_all('row')

    sheet = pd.DataFrame()
    for row in rows:
        name = row.find('vessel_name').text.strip()
        no = row.find('vessel_no').text.strip()
        dir = row.find('direction').text.strip()
        barno = row.find('num_barges').text.strip()
        arr = row.find('arrival_date').text.strip()

        try:
            end = row.find('end_of_lockage').text.strip()
        except:
            result = ''

        df = pd.DataFrame([[name,no,dir,barno,arr, end]], columns=['Name','Vessel No.','Direction','Number of Barges','Arrival', 'End of Lockage'])
        sheet = sheet.append(df,sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

    results.append(sheet)


def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
    with ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
        for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
            df.to_excel(writer,'%s' %lockName[n],index=False,)
        writer.save()

save_xls(results,excel_file_full)
print('----done----')
```

Error:

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py:329: UserWarning: Calling close() on already closed file.
  warn("Calling close() on already closed file.")
```

I put the save part in a `try except` block according to [this help doc](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_check_close.html), but I must be doing it wrong.

```
while True:
    try:
        def save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path):
            with ExcelWriter(xls_path) as writer:
                for n, df in enumerate(list_dfs):
                    df.to_excel(writer,'%s' %lockName[n],index=False,)
                writer.save()

        save_xls(results,excel_file_full)
    except xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError as e:
        print(e)
print('----done----')
```

Comment: It is not an Error, it is a Warning. That is why try...except does not catch it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The warning occurs because the program is using `to_excel()` within a `with` statement which effectively closes/saves the file once it leaves the scope. It then calls `save()` which tries to close the file again but since it is already closed you get a warning.

In short remove the `save()` and you won't get the warning but the file will still be saved.

Comment: Thanks. A bit late to the party, but removing ```writer.save()``` resulted in the script completing successfully without the warning.

Comment: I wish my colleagues have googled this warning as well...